# sql view selecting from multiple databases, proxy user doesn't have access to remote database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, view, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I've set up multiple views in a sql server database.  These views are are selected from in a stored procedure which has WITH EXECUTE AS 'proxyuser' clause in it's declaration.  The select statement it executes is created dynamically, and executed with the sp_executesql stored procedure.  Everything has worked correctly until it became necessary to include a join to a table in a different database in the definition of one of those views, so that the view is selecting from both the database where it resides and another database on the same server.

The error I'm getting is this: The server principal "proxyuser" is not able to access the database "mydb" under the current security context.

This is what I've tried:

1. Deleting the proxyuser from the second database and mapping the login to the database as recommended here..
   http://sqlmusings.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/issue-server-principal-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-under-the-current-security-context/
2. Enabling cross database ownership chaining as recommended here..
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/07dcab8c-b830-4ca9-8afc-3e75772f44d3/

and my scenario doesn't meet the requirements outlined by Microsoft Support Article #913422, which describes the same error message. The proxy uses Sql Server Authentication, not Windows Authentication.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finally coming back to this after a long side-track working on a different project.  I worked it out so that I'm no longer using the WITH EXECUTE AS 'proxyuser' syntax.  The user I was connecting with had sufficient permissions to perform the action.  I'm not sure why I didn't try that before.